# Thumbnail path from video in Android

Tags: android, video, bitmap

I have this path of video in android - `file:///storage/emulated/0/Images/nature.mp4` and I want to get the path of the `bitmap` of the thumbnail extracted from the video and not the `bitmap` object itself so that I can load the thumbnail using `picasso` library like for the `images` url

```
Picasso.with(con).load(image_url).into(holder.Img);
```

I've looked at the similar question on the site but it wasn't clear enough for my case.

Comment: You can load bitmap with Picasso too

Comment: @Bhargav I've tried getting bitmap but it came out to be null.I also improvised the code but was still facing the null pointer exception.refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585696/cant-get-bitmap-out-of-video-in-sdcard-in-android